# How to change tab title at runtime added in OnCreate method?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am using this code

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.workflow_layout);

        ColorDrawable color=new ColorDrawable(Color.ParseColor("#1f3d55"));
        ActionBar.SetBackgroundDrawable (color);
        ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled (true);

        ActionBar.SetIcon (new ColorDrawable (new Color (global::Android.Resource.Color.Transparent)));
        ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled (true);

        Intent i = new Intent ().SetClass (this, typeof(Screens.WorkflowedToMeTab));
        TabHost.AddTab (TabHost.NewTabSpec ("").SetIndicator ("Workflowed To Me (" + FolderViewerActivity.count + ")").SetContent (i));
        TabHost.TabWidget.GetChildAt (0).SetBackgroundResource (Resource.Drawable.tab_shape);
        TabHost.TabWidget.GetChildAt (0).LayoutParameters.Height = TabHost.TabWidget.GetChildAt (0).LayoutParameters.Height * 2 / 3;
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem/error, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to change the title of tab that i was added code: TabHost.AddTab (TabHost.NewTabSpec ("").SetIndicator ("Workflowed To Me (" + FolderViewerActivity.count + ")").SetContent (i)); on onresume method.

Comment: means this tab title : TabHost.NewTabSpec